# Why Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I have a general question about the Blockchain technology. I understand how it works in principle, but what problems does it solve? I mean we could have a similar system, where everyone has addresses and private keys and when they wish to make a transaction, they just distribute it to everyone. Without blocks or mining but decentralised and distributed as it is. Of course, a small transaction fee would be required to avoid spam. Where does this go wrong?

Comment: Hi there. I've flagged this as off-topic, as it's not specifically about Ethereum (and it's also quite broad). I'd suggest trying the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site, which has a broader remit and deals with general blockchain queries. (At least according to their Help Centre.) https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The double-spend problem**

For example, you transmit the same 5 ether to two different addresses, and broadcast both transactions (A and B) to different nodes. Obviously, only one of those transactions should be allowed. Otherwise you could easily duplicate your money.

The nodes start relaying both transactions to other nodes, but eventually some nodes will receive both A and B. Of those nodes, some will receive A first and some will receive B first. Now, how does the network determine which one is real? Half of the network believes A was first, and half believes B was first.

You can't solve this by including a timestamp in transactions, because that can easily be forged.

Mining solves this problem by creating a consensus mechanism which allows the entire network to agree on one ordering of transactions. Conveniently, it also introduces a way to distribute new coins.